# Selenium and proxy switching

Tags: selenium, proxy

is there a universal command which I could use to change and apply a proxy to the current session? I'd need this for main ones like firefox, chrome, etc.

I've looked extensively and it seems like I can only set that up upon initiation, is there a way I can do this? I'm running OSX Lion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used OSX command to apply a proxy to the whole system, this was the only way I found.